# I keep getting an unauthorised access error when trying to upload files to custom vision on Azure

Tags: azure

I was following the AI school tutorial on azure using custom vision and I believe I setup everything correctly although there is a part in the tutorial which asks you to enter the API details into the "NotePad" in the quick access tab which I couldn't for the life of me find. 
Anyhow I moved on and did the rest except when I try to upload files from the terminal I get the following error -

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
   at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training.TrainingApi.GetDomainsWithHttpMessagesAsync(Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training.TrainingApiExtensions.GetDomainsAsync(ITrainingApi operations, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training.TrainingApiExtensions.GetDomains(ITrainingApi operations)
   at Import.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Import/Program.cs:line 29
```

I tried to set the permissions but nothing I've tried has worked, does anyone have any pointers it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a million.

Comment: can you provide the code?

Comment: Its at https://aischool.microsoft.com/en-us/services/learning-paths/sketch2code/

Comment: Post what you tried

Comment: I just followed the tutorial up until the step where it asks you to go into the import folder via terminal. And then ran "dotnet run". I really never strayed from the tutorial at all except at the notepad part. Also I use Mac if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

You have to update Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training package.

The solution that worked for me:

1. Open your terminal and go to the Import folder
2. Run the following command `dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training --version 2.0.0`
3. Open Program.cs and replace this line:

   `TrainingApi trainingApi = new TrainingApi() { ApiKey = trainingKey };`

   with this line:

   `CustomVisionTrainingClient trainingApi = new CustomVisionTrainingClient(new  ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(trainingKey)) {Endpoint = endpoint};`

   make sure to replace ENDPOINT with your yours from [customvision.ai](https://www.customvision.ai/)